# NetBeans не запускает GlassFish

Tags: glassfish, netbeans

Дело вот в чем, скачаю NetBeans с офф сайта. Во время инстала ставлю вместе с ним GlassFish . В общем скачиваю фул версию и ставлю просто все, что можно. После инстала запускаю NetBeans, создаю проект-пример "Пример JSP". Разворачиваю проект. Первый раз все проходит отлично все работает как надо. Но стоит закрыть страницу с примерами, добавить в любом месте кода пробел (для того, что проект изменился) и развернуть заново, как NetBeans подвисает на шаге "запуск GlassFish" висит так 20 минут и потом отваливается со словами "не могу запустить GlassFish" (при это в логах ничего не пишется). Перезапустить NetBeans или перезапустить систему не помогает. Пробовал переустанавливать - тоже самое.

То есть NetBeans после инстала только один раз стартует сервер и все. Больше его как будто нет. Это происходит с любым проектом.

На просторах сети такие проблемы встречаются, но решения не нашел. Сам GlassFish стартует  из командной строки без всяких проблем. Пишут, что нужно дать доступ всем группам пользователей к папке с сервером на любые действия - не помогло. Пишут, что нужно прописать пути PATH (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin) и JAVA_HOME (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07) - не помогло. Запускать NetBeans из под админа - не помогло.

Есть идеи по этому поводу?

Comment: @VorobyevEvgeniy, проверьте порт 8080 на наличие приложений, использующих его. Плюс текст ошибки - он может не запускаться по миллиону разных причин

Comment: Ну конечно, сделал это первым делом. Еще раз повторю, сто из консоли сервер стартует нормально и работает на этом порту. Да и ошибка при попытке запуска на забитом порту - другая.

Comment: @VorobyevEvgeniy, извините, что не могу отличить ошибки по сферическому описанию оных

Comment: Да ничего страшного!
Может быть забыл сказать, но после 20 минутного таймаута развертка проекта отваливается со словами "не могу запустить GlassFish" при этом не выводя в логи ничего

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение найдено! Нужно создать новый домен. Прошу заметить, это не означает, что стандартный порт был занят. Я удалил GlassFish из списка серверов NetBeans'a и добавил его заново руками - не взлетело. Потом попробовал тоже самое и создал вместо дефолт-домена, другой домен на том же порту (8080). Все заработало.

Comment: супер, 2 дня ковырял, пока не прочитал. была ошибка :1050. в итоге удалил сервер, папку домена, которая находилась по адресу C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.0\glassfish\domains, создал все по новой и заработало. увидим как часто придется это повторять

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй изменить путь для твоего проекта так, чтобы в нём не было русских букв..(если посмотришь domain.xml то внутри в самом конце будут данные для твоего проекта задеплоеного на сервер

---

> application context-root="/WebApplication3" object-type="user" 
>   directory-deployed="true" name="WebApplication3"
>   location="file:/C:/NetBeansProjects/WebApplication3/build/web/">
>   property name="appLocation" value="file:/C:/NetBeansProjects

) 
если в пути к папке твоего проекта, или в имени твоего проекта, будут русские буквы, то в файле ты найдешь - **кракозябры** :

> application context-root="/Library_2" object-type="user" 
>   name="Library_2" directory-deployed="true"
>   location="file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Aly/ͮ襲0寪etBeansProjects/Library_2/build/web/">
>   property name="appLocation" 
>   value="file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Aly/ͮ襲0寪etBeansProjects/Library_2/build/web/">

..........................................................................
а если русских букв нет, то и путь будет правильный.
Когда изменишь путь своего проекта без русских букв, то и 
после этого сможешь его деплоить, стартовать , перезагружать и т.д. 
и забудь про ANSI.

Как сейчас этого избежать:

Вариант 1.

1. Создавая проект, указывай путь к проекту и имя проекта, без русских букв.

Вариант 2.

1. Удалить все секции {application} из файла domain.xml c русскими буквами.
2. Перезапустить NetBeans.

Вариант 3.

1. Правой кнопкой на твоём проекте.
2. Если имя проекта содержит русские буквы, выбрать переименовать проект.
3. Указать имя без русских букв.
4. Если папка проекта содержит русские буквы, выбрать переместить проект.
5. Указать путь к папке проекта без русских букв.

Answer (score 0):

после первой остановки сервера та же проблема

Answer (score 0):

После недельных изысканий пришел к такому решению:
после перезапуска серверка GlassFish из NetBeans-а иногда портится файл *\domains\domain1\config\domain.xml
NetBeans меняет в нем кодировку на ANSI. Если у вас завис процесс запуска GlassFish в NetBeans-е и в логе тишина, то нужно:

1. вернуть кодировку файла domain.xml
       обратно в UTF-8 (без BOM);
2. остановить домен вручную (ярлык
       "C:\Program
       Files\glassfish-4.0\bin\asadmin.bat"
       stop-domain).

После этого сервер снова начнет работать через NetBeans. (если этого не произошло, то перезапустить NetBeans)